# Unable to Receive Kafka Messages in Spring Cloud Stream Consumer with Java 17

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am working on a Spring Cloud Stream application that utilizes Apache Kafka for messaging. In the application, I have set up a REST API to publish messages to a Kafka topic. However, the consumer doesn't seem to receive the messages. I am using Spring Cloud Stream's **`StreamBridge`** to send messages.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import ma.enset.KafkaSpringCloudStream.entity.PageEvent;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PageEventRestController {
    private StreamBridge streamBridge;
    @GetMapping("/publish/{topic}/{name}")
    private PageEvent publish(@PathVariable("topic") String topic,@PathVariable("name") String name){
        PageEvent pageEvent = PageEvent.builder()
                .name(name)
                .user(Math.random()>0.5 ? "User1" : "User2")
                .date(new Date((long) (Math.random()*System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .duration(new Random().nextInt(9001))
                .build();
        streamBridge.send(topic,pageEvent);
        return pageEvent;
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class PageEventService {
    @Bean
    public Consumer<PageEvent> pageEventConsumer(){

        return (input) -> {
            System.out.println("********************************");
            System.out.println(input.toString());
            System.out.println("********************************");
        };
    }
}
```

```
spring.application.name=app
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.pageEventConsumer-in-0.destination=testTopic
```

Comment: I suggest you add more logging and debug further. How do you know the producer actually sent anything to Kafka for the consumer to read? Simply calling producer send function doesn't actually make an immediate request to Kafka. Where is StreamBridge defined or injected from? Have you tried starting with [unit tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-introducing) rather than directly using external systems like Kafka to verify your code works?

Comment: Also, consumer bindings without a `group` have `auto.offset.reset` set to `latest` by default so, if the record is already in the topic when the consumer it started, it won't be received. Add `group` if you want to read existing records and track comitted offsets for the next time the consumer is started.